# How to Pass a Parameter in the URL in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have made a report using SSRS and would like to include parameters in a URL.

Currently the URL to the report is:

```
https://SPSite/sites/it/systems/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/sites/it/systems/sharepoint%20reports/IT%20Group%20Projects.rdl&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fevshare%2Fsites%2Fit%2Fsystems%2Fsharepoint%2520reports%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx
```

The Parameters id like to set:

```
Parameter1=Test1
Parameter2=Test2
```

I've tried adding the parameters to the end of the URL in the form of

```
 &Parameter1=Test1&Parameter2=Test2
```

but it does not load the report with the parameters.

I've tried building the URL based off of this (which I found in the answer section of another similar question):

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<path>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render&UserID='fred'
```

Which ended up looking like:

```
http://SPSite/sites/it/systems/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?%2fRelativeReportUrl=/sites/it/systems/sharepoint%20reports/IT%20Group%20Projects.rdl%2fIT%20Group%20Projects.rdl&rs:Command=Render&Parameter1=Test1&Parameter2=Test2
```

But unfortunately it still does not work.

Am I missing anything obvious? Currently the default for both parameters is set to "No default value" in the report builder.

Thank you in advance for any info, and apologies if something like this has been answered before!

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/

Comment: Check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url. It mentions adding "_vti_bin" to the URL for requests made through SharePoint.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Thank you Chris, I had seen that but couldn't get it to work for some reason, but after prefixing my parameters with rp: instead as suggested in the link you posted, I got it to work perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass paramater to the SUB report (.rdl) then you have to use like below:

```
<main report url>.rdl&rp3%a[parameter value in report]=[passed value].
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver16